# Variable scope in the shell level

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Recently I have been reading [*The Advanced Bash Script*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and I find something about *the variable scope* between parent and children shells puzzle me so much. Here it is:

Scene:
there are some ways to spawn a child shell: 
first, `(command-lists)`; 
second, execute a non-built-in command or a script, and so on.

Since when we run a script in the parent script, the child script can not see the variables in the parent shell.  Why is it possible that in the `(command-lists)` struct the child shell can seen the variable in the parent shell.
e.g

1. (command-lists)

   ```
   $ a=100
   $ (echo $a)
   100
   $
   ```
2. run a script

   ```
   $ cat b.sh
   echo $a
   $ a=100
   $ ./b.sh
   # empty
   ```

How?

Answer (score 8):

In the case where you have a sub-shell run in the original script:

```
(command1; command2; ...)
```

the sub-shell is a direct copy of the original shell created by `fork()`, and therefore has direct access to its own copy of all the original variables available to it.

Suppose the commands (`command1`, `command2` etc) in the sub-shell are themselves shell scripts.  Those commands are executed by the sub-shell calling `fork()` and then `exec()` to create a new shell, and the new shell does not inherit the non-exported variables from the original shell.

---

Addressing your examples directly:

```
$ a=100
$ (echo $a)
100
$
```

Here, the sub-shell has its own copy of all the variables (specifically, `a`) that the parent shell had access to.  Any changes made in the sub-shell will not be reflected in the parent shell, of course, so:

```
$ a=100
$ (echo $a; a=200; echo $a)
100
200
$ echo $a
100
$
```

Now your second example:

```
$ cat b.sh
echo $a
$ a=100
$ ./b.sh

$ . ./b.sh
100
$ source ./b.sh
100
$ a=200 ./b.sh
200
$ echo $a
100
$ export a
$ ./b.sh
100
$
```

The variable `a` is not exported, so the first time `b.sh` is run, it has no value for `$a` so it echoes an empty line.  The second two examples are a 'cheat'; the shell reads the script `b.sh` as if it was part of the current shell (no `fork()`) so the variables are still accessible to `b.sh`, hence it echoes 100 each time.  (Dot or `.` is the older mechanism for reading a script in the current shell; the Bourne shell in 7th Edition UNIX used it.  The `source` command is borrowed from the C shells as an equivalent mechanism.)

The command `a=200 ./b.sh` exports `a` for the duration of the command, so `b.sh` sees and echoes the modified value `200` but the main shell has `a` unchanged.  Then when `a` is exported, it is available to `b.sh` automatically, hence it sees and echoes the last 100.

Comment: A point I made in my now-deleted answer: try your second example with `export a=100` instead of `a=100`.

Comment: e...Can you make it more clear?"Inside those commands," what this mean?

Comment: @chepner yeah, export works well. But the point here is the sub_shell fork philosophy.

Comment: +1. Re: "the sub-shell has direct access to all the variables (specifically, `a`) that the parent shell had access to": Since (as you point out) "Any changes made in the sub-shell will not be reflected in the parent shell", I think it would be better to write, "the sub-shell has **copies of** all the variables (specifically, `a`) that the parent shell had.

Comment: @ruakh: thanks for the suggestion; I've added it more or less, but in my own words.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hi, thank you for you patient explanations. With your guide, I found the point of my problem is to understand the progress of the command execution in Linux. So I think if you can make it more clear that what really matters is the fork-and-exec progress, rather than anything else.Details as follows:

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Continue the upper one, Details as follows:in the first case that the command is executed in () struct, the sub-shell forked  by the () is a copy of the parent script and any command in it execute in the fork-and-exec progress, so the variable in the parent  process can be accessed;

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Continue the upper one: However, in the second case by running a separate script, the real command is that 'sh xxx.sh' while that sh is a external command, so the parent progress fork a sub-shell and in the sub-shell exec overlay the copy of the parent , which clear nearly everything except the pid, so the variable of the parent is invisible now. Which I think may make it more clear and you can check it by the strace -ff comamnd.

Comment: @twalberg you misunderstand the variable expansion, which is only executed before the corresponding command. As it worked as your mentioned, a=10; (a=20;echo $a) would got the 10, rather than the 20.Here is something useful for you:https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html.